# Store String input as array Java

Tags: java, arrays

**Error**:

> incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

**Goal**: I would like to get the student names from user input

Here is my code

```
public class HelloWorld {
    final static int NUM_STUDENTS = 5;
    final static int NUM_TESTS = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] studentNames = getStudentNames();
        double[][] gradebook = getGradebook();

        printGradeBook(studentNames, gradebook);
    }

    public static String[] getStudentNames() {
        String[] studentName = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < studentName.length; i++) {
            studentName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a name" + (i + 1) + ": ");
        }
        return studentName;
    }
```

Comment: The error is at which line ?

Comment: studentName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a name" + (i+1) +": ");

Comment: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

Comment: I doubt that the `showInputDialog` method is the line which throws the error. They all return a `String` and are not `void` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), see [image](https://i.imgur.com/NyP6USx.png)). Instead of guessing, show us the **full** error message (including stacktrace).

Comment: I want to return the student names so I can print them later on.

Comment: Like @Zabuza says, please paste the stack trace.

Comment: Please give a full example, that we can build. Here it almost impossible to guess... Please give at least the stack trace

Comment: I am using https://www.compilejava.net/. Thats all the code that I have.

Comment: BTW, in your `JOptionPane` call, you might want a space after the word `name`.

Comment: What about the stacktrace?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] (emphasis on **complete**), post all details of the error message. Even your *online compiler* provides more information than you presented, see [test image](https://i.imgur.com/7WqMYpJ.png).

Comment: I'm not even sure if that *online compiler* allows you to create GUI popups. Probably not. Maybe thats the reason. Why aren't you programming on your own machine?

Comment: @TrippKinetics If it won't even compile, presumably there is no stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

*Wanted to comment, but I don't have the reps enough*

The code you posted does work, you are probably trying to get a single students name. In this case just loop through them and add it to a String.

```
String studentName = "";

for (String s: studentNames) {
        if(s.equals("Name you're looking for")){
          studentName = s;
        }          
    }
```